# Media queries with edge css hack

Tags: css, media-queries

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto){.selector {max-width: 25rem;}}
```

The above code is not working as I expected.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is unanswerable. You tell us it is not working as expected but don't tell us how you expect it to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to target div class of `.selector`, when below 1200px **and** using the Microsoft Edge browser, this is what you want. You missed out on a closing bracket.

```css
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  @supports (-ms-ime-align: auto) {
    .selector {
      max-width: 25rem;
    }
  }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zL6jxu4m/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Marc's above code works. However, if you have one of these multiple screen resolution queries active on the same css,

```
@media (min-width: 1281px) and (max-width: 1600px) {
#exampletextareatotest{color:#ff0000;}
}
```

Edge will make it overwrite Marc's query entirely.

By adding one of the following css line examples to your multiple screen resolution/Edge-Specific media queries, you will be able to govern over multiple screen queries and Edge at the same time.

```
@supports (-ms-ime-align: auto) {#exampletextareatotest{color:#00ff00;}
```

Complete Example:

```
@media (min-width: 1281px) and (max-width: 1600px) {
.screenresexampleNOTrequiredbyEdge{.seekbar:width:200px;}
@supports (-ms-ime-align: auto) {#textthatneedstobedifferentoncertainscreenresolutionsaswellasjustedge{color:#00ff00;}
}
```

Hope that helps someone!